# Unexpected Syntax Error when executing python script from windows terminal

Tags: python

When i execute this script pasting it directly on a python console all is fine. But when i use "> python script_name.py" from my windows terminal i get a Syntax error on line 4. It sure is a silly thing but i'm not able to find the issue.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\img"):
    for name in files:
        if ".py" in name:
            break
        i = "-i " + name
        o = " -o _" + name
        s = " -s 0.5"
        print("img.py " + i + o + s)
        os.system("python img.py " + i + o + s)
```

Terminal output:

```
File "tasker.py", line 4
    for name in files 
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks!

Edited to add terminal output.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: try printing content of `files` and see whether correct files are being shown

Comment: `for name in files` missing a colon in the terminal output?

Comment: The error keep showing.

Comment: Sorry i was editing a different file from what i was executing. Silly me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the terminal output window, line 4 in the executed file tasker.py is missing a colon, as such:

```
for name in files
```

You need to add a colon, like this:

```
for name in files:
```

Either change the syntax in the executed file, which is in this case tasker.py, or execute your original code that you posted.